# How does a window driver send and receive data from hardware

Tags: linux, windows, io, kernel, driver

When creating a windows (or for linux) driver for hardware connected to the usb-bus how exactly does one communicate with the usb port?

Does one open a file (pipe) to the corresponding usb port or are other methods used?

Comment: Shared memory (often IO Mapped memory). In part there were also I/O ports (but I think now they are mostly unused). The microcontroller on the motherboard will handle them: where to read or write (e.g. RAM and which chips), ROM, ... -- note: here "memory" is abstract: an selected address and data (so possible an address which it is not in RAM)

Comment: A driver for the USB host controller itself will directly read and write hardware (likely through memory-mapped I/O as @GiacomoCatenazzi mentioned).  Drivers for devices connected to the bus (on the other side of the host controller) will be layered on top of the host controller driver and use its facilities for detecting and configuring endpoints and exchanging data.

Answer (score -1):

To communicate with a USB port in a Windows or Linux driver, you can use the `WinUSB API` (Windows) or `ioctl` function calls (Linux). In Windows, the `WinUSB API` allows you to open a file handle to the device and obtain the necessary handle for subsequent operations. This handle is stored in a structure `(DEVICE_DATA)` defined in the `device.h` file. Once the handle is acquired, the driver can perform operations like reading and writing data to bulk and interrupt endpoints.

For Linux, you can use ioctl function calls to special files for USB device communication. In your program, you can open the corresponding file using `open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR)` and then use `write` and `read` functions to send and receive characters through the USB port. **Matt Cutts** detailed *how to complile Simple USM Program in Linux* in his [blog](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/compile-a-simple-usb-program-in-linux/)

For windows read [Connect USB devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb) which also talks about USBIP tools in Linux.

Comment: You've discussed the communication between application and kernel.  The question is clearly about the communication between kernel and hardware.